# Wordpress filter not being added

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress

I have a plugin that uses `apply_filters` like this:

```
$additional_fields = apply_filters('attachment_meta_add_fields', $additional_fields);
```

In my theme's `functions.php`, I do:

```
function addAttachmentMeta($additionalFields) {
    return $addtionalFields;
}
add_filter( 'attachment_meta_add_fields', 'addAttachmentMeta', 1, 1 );
```

But the function `addAttachmentMeta` never runs.

How can I alter my apply or add filter statements to make it so that `addAttachmentMeta` gets called?

Edit:
This is a custom plugin that I wrote based off tutorials on how to add additional attachment meta fields. The whole source is here: http://pastebin.com/7NcjDsK5.  As I mentioned in the comments, I know this is running and working because I can add additional fields in this plugin file, but not by using the filters because the filter doesn't get added.

I can see var_dumps before and after the `apply_filters` statement, but the function I've pointed to with `add_filter` never gets called.

Comment: try changing priority ?

Comment: 0 - 1000, still won't run.  Note that I didn't try EVERY number between 0 and 1000.

Comment: is that plugin currently active on your wordpress ?

Comment: Yes.  I've also made sure that the functions in the plugin get called, and they are.  But this `apply_filters` statement is outside the plugin's main class.  It's just in the plugin.php file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [order WordPress' core loads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikkIU.png), function.php gets called after all plugins are loaded and executed.

You need to make sure the `apply_filters()` in your plugin runs AFTER your `add_filter()` is called. Otherwise at the point where your filters are 'applied', `add_filter()` simply hasn't been called yet.

What you could do is use a hook to make that part of your plugin run after functions.php has loaded. You could use the [`add_action('after_setup_theme', 'function_name')`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_setup_theme) hook.

Wrap the last three lines of your plugin file inside a function and execute it after functions.php runs.

```
function addAttachmentMeta() {
    $additional_fields = array();
    $additional_fields = apply_filters('attachment_meta_add_fields', $additional_fields);
    $am = new Attachment_Meta( $additional_fields );
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'addAttachmentMeta');
```

Comment: I also use `add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', array( $this, 'addFields' ), 11, 2 );` in my plugin.  If I adjust the timing of when it runs, it seems as though this filter never gets added.

Comment: Is this a related question? Or is this a result of the above suggested fix?

Comment: A result of the suggested fix.

Comment: Marking as correct because this solves the original question.