# add_filter function not getting called in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, add-filter

I have created a custom_post_type in wordpress file. But I have trouble in adding a filter function. The filter function does not seem to be evoked? alpha_set_contact_coloumns() is not providing any result.

```
<?php

$contact = get_option( 'activate_contact' );
if(@$contact == 1){
  add_action( 'init', 'alpha_contact_custom_post_type' );
  add_filter( 'manage_alpha-contact_posts_coloumns', 'alpha_set_contact_coloumns' );
}


function alpha_contact_custom_post_type() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'          => 'Messages',
    'singular_name' => 'Message',
    'menu_name'     => 'Messages',
    'name_admin_bar'=> 'Message'
  );

  $args = array(
    'labels'        => $labels,
    'show_ui'       => true,
    'show_in_menu'  => true,
    'capability_type'=> 'post',
    'hierarchical'  => false,
    'menu_position' => 26,
    'menu_icon'     => 'dashicons-email-alt',
    'supports'      => array('title', 'editor', 'author')
  );

  register_post_type( 'alpha-contact', $args );
}

function alpha_set_contact_coloumns( $coloumns ) {
  unset( $coloumns['author']);
  return $coloumns;
}
```

Comment: `coloumns` is not spelt correctly... the filter is `manage_{post-type}_posts_columns`

Comment: Take look at this answers: [Wordpress filter not being added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19277932/wordpress-filter-not-being-added) [add_filter does not work as expected](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/183376/add-filter-does-not-work-as-expected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

Spelling mistake in code. I replaced this code `manage_contact_posts_coloumns` with `manage_alpha-contact_posts_columns`.

it is **columns** not `coloumns`.

```
$contact = get_option( 'activate_contact' );

if(@$contact == 1){
  add_action( 'init', 'alpha_contact_custom_post_type' );
  add_filter( 'manage_alpha-contact_posts_columns', 'alpha_set_contact_coloumns' );
}


function alpha_contact_custom_post_type() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'          => 'Messages',
    'singular_name' => 'Message',
    'menu_name'     => 'Messages',
    'name_admin_bar'=> 'Message'
  );

  $args = array(
    'labels'        => $labels,
    'show_ui'       => true,
    'show_in_menu'  => true,
    'capability_type'=> 'post',
    'hierarchical'  => false,
    'menu_position' => 26,
    'menu_icon'     => 'dashicons-email-alt',
    'supports'      => array('title', 'editor', 'author')
  );

  register_post_type( 'alpha-contact', $args );
}

function alpha_set_contact_coloumns( $coloumns ) {      
  unset( $coloumns['author']);
  return $coloumns;
}
```

Comment: It helped. Missed out keyword 'column'

Comment: I dont have the reputation to upvote your answer. Sorry