# add_filter not being fired/called from custom plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, filter

I'm facing an issue that I can't seem to figure out.

I have a plugin where it has filters that lets you change modify some of its data.

I have a simply class method like this inside the plugin:

```
public static function getAllowedColors(){
  $colors = array(
    'green',
    'blue',
  );
 return apply_filters('my_allowed_colors', $colors);
}
```

This method is used throughout the plugin like this `Colors::getAllowedColors()` but it should be filterable so third party plugins or devs can change it.

The issue is that I created and **activated** a small custom plugin, that doesn't have any classes or anything..just the main plugin file with the required plugin headers and in that file, I did the usual:

```
function add_allowed_color($colors){
 $colors[] = 'black';
 return $colors;
}
add_filter('my_allowed_colors', 'add_allowed_color');
```

For some reason the new color never gets added when `getAllowedColors()` is called...

I added a dump statement inside the `getAllowedColors()` method, and then a dump statement inside the small custom plugin main plugin file (where the add_filter exists) and I can see that `getAllowedColors` is being called before the small custom plugin.

I'm aware that `add_filter` needs to be fired before `apply_filters` so that your changes can take effect...but I'm not sure how exactly to make sure that my little custom plugin **always** runs BEFORE the main plugin with all its classes and functionality.

I stumbled across this answer for a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19279650/4484799 but it wouldn't be applicable in this case since this `getAllowedColors()` is a utility method that gets called when needed throughout the plugin.

---

In the small custom plugin I also tried adjusting the code to this:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', function(){

    function add_allowed_color($colors){
        $colors[] = 'black';
        return $colors;
    }

    add_filter('my_allowed_colors', 'add_allowed_color');
});
```

Though this is valid PHP, and if I called `add_allowed_color('test')` at the bottom of its definition, it returns `test`, the filter however still doesn't work.

I want to know how I can make use of this filter? What is preventing it from working? I've used `add_filter` several times before between several different plugins especially WooCommerce which has a ton of filters but I can't figure out why this isn't working

Any help is appreciated

Comment: If you have two plugins, A and B, and A is the one with the `getAllowedColors()` method and B is the one with the filter that adds black, then A will load before B. Usually that is not an issue. However, if you do __any__ work in A before every other plugin (or theme) gets loaded, then B won't have a chance to register its hook. If your plugin needs to "boot" up some logic, you can move that to the `plugins_loaded` action which guarantees that all plugins have loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to start by saying something you already know: WordPress is extended by hooks.

As I said, I know you know this, but I'd further clarify it by saying: WordPress **should only** be extended by hooks.

What I mean by that is that any code **not** run in a hook should also make no assumptions about the state of WordPress.

Based on comments by the OP, they have a singleton or controller or similar that boots up when their plugin entry file is executed. This is a very common pattern for plugins, and by itself isn't necessarily right or wrong as long as this code only does PHP things such as instantiating classes, registering autoloaders or creating global functions, or registers WordPress actions/filters. If this code does anything else specific to WordPress, that's where trouble can creep in.

The reason for the trouble is that you have no guarantee that other plugins have been loaded, and it is absolutely certain that the theme hasn't been either. And because these haven't been loaded, they haven't had a chance to register their filters.

Even something as simple as [`get_option`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/) has at least six hooks that could be called in its lifecycle, and the simple translation function [`__`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/) has two. Also, "simple" functions such as [`get_home_url`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_home_url/) still call `get_option` behind the scenes. Using any of these functions outside of a hook could lead to unexpected results.

As a developer it really helps to understand the load order, at least a high level:

1. WordPress begins the general load
2. Dropins are loaded
3. More WordPress loading including database
4. Must-use plugins are loaded
5. Active plugins are loaded
6. The theme is loaded
7. The user is authenticated

For each of the last four in that list, once that specific step is completed there is also a corresponding hook:

1. [`muplugins_loaded`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/muplugins_loaded/)
2. [`plugins_loaded`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/plugins_loaded/)
3. [`after_setup_theme`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/after_setup_theme/)
4. [`init`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/)

If you run code that interacts with WordPress in any way (beyond filters) before the corresponding hook runs, you should assume other code at that level hasn't run. For instance, if you are writing a plugin that executes code on entry, that means `plugins_loaded`, `after_setup_theme` and `init` haven't run, and it is totally possible that other plugins and themes haven't registered any hooks. Similarly, if your plugin runs code in the `plugins_loaded` loaded hook, then it should be assumed that the theme hasn't been booted yet so it hasn't registered any hooks.

Sidenote: Plugins should not register the `muplugins_loaded` hook, and themes should not register the `plugins_loaded` hook because by the time registration happens, the hook has already run. I've definitely seen this happen several times in developer's code.

## tl;dr

Unless you need something more specific, the vast majority of code in a plugin can be invoked via the [`init`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/) hook because at this point the bulk of WordPress has been loaded.

Further, there's usually no advantage of creating your singleton "sooner than later". However, if your singleton is the one that does all the additional hook registration (another common pattern I see), it might be worth moving that code so that the singleton can be used for its instance methods only by the code that needs it.

### Edit

I'll amend this by saying that sometimes things appear to work depending on the plugin load order which is generally alphabetical.

If you have plugins *A* and *B*, and plugin *A* happens to load before *B*, then it will be able to register its hooks before *B* needs them.

This should only be considered working by coincidence however. The plugin load order can actually be changed, or you or the other plugin author might rename your plugin some day.

Comment: Thank you for adding the answer. I actually have a boilerplate plugin which I use to spin up plugins and it operates a bit how you've noticed. I will update it to run on the `init` hook, you can see it here: https://github.com/UVLabs/wordpress-plugin-boilerplate

The other thing is as you mentioned, the `Main` class is what sets up the instance and then other hooks are called by the `Loader`, is there anything wrong with that approach based on what you see in the linked repo? (you can comment on the repo instead of here)

Comment: I wouldn't say that there's anything wrong with your Loader approach except that you might end up with a false sense of security or view of how the code is run. If you have `add_action()` in your entry point file (or an include) you are all set, and it should be obvious what does what and when. If you have to boot a class via an instance method, and that class loads a loader, and that loader adds actions, you can sometimes get lost in the OOP and have false assumptions. Lots of plugins do it that way to be clear, so I'm not saying it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

@ChrisHaas has it right. In your small custom plugin, add your filter from a 'plugins_loaded' action handler instead of the one you used. 'plugins_loaded' doesn't fire until everything is initialized with all the plugins in use.

Comment: Actually, I think it isn't "small custom plugin" with the `add_filter` call that is the problem. I think that in the main plugin something is making a call to `Colors::getAllowedColors()` before all plugins have loaded. For instance, I often see people declare/include of their classes and then call `MyMainClass::init()` or something, and that's what I think is being done too early.

Comment: @ChrisHaas You're right, that is how I've been creating them, in the main plugin file I typically just call an instance of the bootstrap logic without hooking into any action.

Its interesting how this has never became a problem or caught my attention until now, I've actually created other little custom plugins to filter my main plugin and they worked fine, its just due to this particular method not filtering I was able to realize something is wrong. Please submit an answer explaining why the main plugin file should always be attached to an action and what it can cause if not and I'll accept